# How to prevent automatic unit test execution in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

Every time I compile my solution the unit-tests start to run in background as I see in the Test Explorer.

Is there any configuration to prevent VS from doing that?

Comment: Do you have this setting enabled? http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/run-a-unit-test-after-build-in-vs.aspx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disable the "**Run Tests after Build**" setting:

[image: Run Tests after Build setting]

Source:
http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/run-a-unit-test-after-build-in-vs.aspx

Comment: I have this enabled in VS2015 and there appears to be no way to disable it.

Answer (score 3):

My problem: I have 'Run Tests After Build' Off. Although the test cases are not running, the test discovery itself is running for minutes after every build.  Below setting fixed my problem.

[image: TestExecutionCheck]

Under Test->Test Settings-> uncheck 'Keep Test Execution Engine Running'. I am using VS 2015.