# Possible to turn off automatic run of tests in Visual Studio 2017 every time I build my local solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that includes many tests, but I don't want to automatically run the tests every single time I build. Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio 2017?

I've checked Tools/Options. I've searched for this question in Stack Overflow, but don't find this question.

I've also checked the Solution Properties, but I don't see anything.

This question isn't a duplicate of this Stack Overflow question [How to Prevent automatic test execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596819/how-to-prevent-automatic-unit-test-execution-in-visual-studio-2012) because it deals with the web portal and not Visual Studio 2017 IDE, itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent automatic unit test execution in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596819/how-to-prevent-automatic-unit-test-execution-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: Not a duplicate, because it is not about doing this in Visual Studio itself, for local builds. (Not the Build System from the web portal).

Comment: Ooops. Not a duplicate, because it is about doing this in Visual Studio itself, for local builds, and not the build system in the web portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried disabling "Run Tests After Build" from the Test Explorer window's toolbar? It should be the first button on the toolbar.

To open the Test Explorer window, go to Test -> Windows -> Test Explorer.

Comment: I see (barely) that the icon for "Run Tests After Build" can be toggled! I did not know that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yep, that's good feedback and I'll share with the team. Thanks, Su.

Answer (score 3):

You first go to `Test` in the main menu, then go to `Windows` and then under the `Windows`, `Run Tests After the Build` button [image]