# How to prevent running test after build in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 15.9.6. After every build all my Tests starts executing. How do i disable it.

There are few [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596819/how-to-prevent-automatic-unit-test-execution-in-visual-studio-2012) posts suggesting to disable `Run Test After Build` option under `Test Settings` menu however i am using  Community edition and i do not see that option available in Community

How do i disable it?